# How to install gems via git in Docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler

I try to develop rails app on docker.

`docker-compose build` is succeed, but the error occured in `docker-compose up`.

In Gemfile, I use rails with github like below.
`gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'`

This cause error in docker-compose up like this

```
web_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:310:in `to_specs': Could not find 'activesupport' (>= 4.2) among 110 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
web_1  | Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/usr/local/bundle:/root/.gem/ruby/2.5.0:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1464:in `block in activate_dependencies'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1453:in `each'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1453:in `activate_dependencies'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1435:in `activate'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:68:in `block in gem'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `gem'
web_1  |    from /hateblocker/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
web_1  |    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
web_1  |    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
hateblocker_web_1 exited with code 1
```

When I edited Gemfile like below, no error occured.

`gem 'rails'`

From error message I found that installing some gems via git failed in container.
Maybe this cause this error.

Is there any way to install gems via git in container?

Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml is [here](https://github.com/colorbox/hateblocker/tree/dockerize).

Comment: you might need to install git in Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `docker-compose.yml`, change:

```
command: bin/rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

to

```
command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

So that it can run `rails` in context of Gemfile.